# "Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationUI.Aero2' or one of its dependencies." Why not?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

In my WPF application, I get the following exception on startup:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 
'PresentationUI.Aero2, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
or one of its dependencies.
```

EDIT: Using fusion log, I get a little more valuable info than the call stack:

```
LOG: DisplayName = PresentationUI.Aero2, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///[...]/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = EngideskLauncher.vshost.exe
Calling assembly : PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: [...]\bin\Debug\EngideskLauncher.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: PresentationUI.Aero2, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///[...]/bin/Debug/PresentationUI.Aero2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///file:///[...]/bin/Debug/PresentationUI.Aero2/PresentationUI.Aero2.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///file:///[...]/bin/Debug/PresentationUI.Aero2.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///file:///[...]/bin/Debug/PresentationUI.Aero2/PresentationUI.Aero2.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

What I find strange, is that the calling assembly is `PresentationFramework`, which is a .NET framework assembly, obviously. A .NET Framework assembly wouldn't call an assembly which is not a .NET framework assembly. Anyway, I can't find a PresentationUI.Aero2.DLL anywhere and not even Google seems to know anything about it??

Any ideas?

Additional information:

- .NET Framework 4.0
- Windows 8.1

Comment: Enable fusion log or use ProcMon to find out what file it is trying to load. See [How to debug “Could not load file or assembly” runtime errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602912/how-to-debug-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-runtime-errors).

Comment: Hi CodeCaster, thanks for the hint. I would be glad, if you could give me short feedback to the output. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Hi Hans,  the folder you mention contains `PresentationFramework.Aero2.DLL` but not `PresentationUI.Aero2.DLL`. What do you mean with "how you got 4.0 on that machine is entirely unguessable"? I cant remember using any sort of sledge hammer ;) Thank you for your help!

Comment: My WPF project (.NET 4.0, Win8.1) is throwing exactly the same exception for any view containing a FlowDocument, but _only_ when I run with the debugger in Visual Studio. If I launch the executable from the `bin` folder, no exception. A separate project I created as a standalone works when run as a standalone project in its own solution, but fails if I add it to my existing solution, so I suspect there's something wrong with my solution.

Comment: Hi pmcoltrane, in my case the bug disappeared by itself and I could not tell, what I changed. I worked in the project which threw the exception and rebuilt it. No idea... That's what you call a Heisen-Bug, I guess. If find out anything, I would be glad if you let me know!

Comment: This answer fixed my similar problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335712/why-cant-windows-7-load-the-assembly-presentationframework-aero2

Comment: You're probably using a FlowDocument or a FlowDocumentScrollViewer or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same error and finally realized that it was simply stopping in the IDE because I had first chance exceptions turned on, the exception doesn't actually matter and you can ignore or continue past it.

Comment: So, this doesn't answer the question as to why the exception is being thrown. Do you have any idea why it is being thrown if we can just ignore it?

Answer (score 18):

If you're interested, this is a (benign) bug in WPF. The exception is first-chance and can be ignored.

WPF forgot to add `Aero2.NormalColor.xaml` to `PresentationUI.dll`. If you inspect `PresentationUI.dll` with your favorite reflector/decompiler, you'll find all sorts of themes, such as `Aero.NormalColor.baml`, etc. but no `Aero2.NormalColor.xaml`. This causes WPF to try and see if an external assembly exists:

This tries to load `Aero2.NormalColor.baml` from `PresentationUI.dll` and returns `null`:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemResources.cs,773

This then goes to try an external assembly:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemResources.cs,554

And this throws the actual exception:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/SystemResources.cs,706

This exception is commonly observed when using a `FlowDocument` or a `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`.